# Ionic 2 **panup** and **pandown** event are not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, hammer.js

I'm working on Ionic  2 project and I want to implement drag and drop feature. For that, I used bellow event in Ionic 2

```
<div  (press) = "onDragInit(item, $event)"
      (panstart)="dragStart($event)"
      (panup)="onDrag($event)"
      (pandown)="onDrag($event)"
      (panend)="onDragEnd($event)"
      (pressup)="pressUpEvent($event)">
</div>
```

The problem is **panup** and **pandown** events are not working for the first time.

If we did a **horizontal move** first then both events are working properly.
But if we did a vertical move first both events are not working until doing a horizontal move. 
Has anyone faced with this problem?

this is my **.ts** file

```
public onDragInit(doc, event): void {
    if(!doc.isSelected){
        return;
    }

    // hide selected docs when start the drag
    this.docs.forEach( (doc: any) => {
        if(doc.isSelected){
            doc.dragging = true;
            this.draggingDocs.push(doc);
        }else{
            doc.dragging = false;
        }
    });
    this.dragPoint = this.getDragPoint(event.center.x, event.center.y);
    this.docDragging = true;
    this.destination = this.getDroppableDoc(event.center.x,event.center.y);

    event.preventDefault()
}

public dragStart(event: any): void {
    if(!this.docDragging){
        return ;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}

public onDrag(event: any):void {
    if(!this.docDragging){
        return ;
    }

    this.dragPoint = this.getDragPoint(event.center.x, event.center.y);
    let placeForDrop = this.getDroppableCar(event.center.x, event.center.y);
    if(placeForDrop != null && placeForDrop.doc != null){
        this.destination = placeForDrop;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}

public onDragEnd(event: any): void {
    if(this.destination && this.destination.doc){
        this.onDrop.emit({draggingDocs: this.draggingDocs,destination: this.destination});
    }

    this.cancelDragging();
    event.preventDefault();
}

public pressUpEvent(event: any): void {
    this.cancelDragging();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Could you add the .ts page that the events are being fired from?

Comment: It seems something changed in a later Ionic2 release. This used to work but now event.center X and Y is always zero on a pan event so its impossible to know exactly where the pan coordinates ended up from what I can see.

Comment: I have also noticed that if I listen to any pan event, if I click and pan left or right before panning up and down it does set the event.center coordinates right, but never if I just click and then pan up and down immediately. Very odd. Seems ionic2 is eating these events for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. Angular 2 provides a token called HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG which accepts a HammerGestureConfig type.

In the simplest way, we can extend HammerGestureConfig like this.

// override default hammer.js settings.

```
import { HammerGestureConfig } from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class MCrewHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  public overrides = {
    "pan": { direction: 30 },
    "press": { time: 300 }
  };
}
```

and add this to providers.

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MCrewHammerConfig },
  ]
```

for more details [angular-2-events](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2).

Comment: still not working for me, maybe because of browser scroll i dont know. panup work for 2 time and pandowe event work for 3 time and then stop !!!